# Back button action of UINavigation Views ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have 4 views.

1st is `rootView` and then `View1`, `View2` & `View3`.
It is working according `rootView-> View1-> View2-> View3` .

I have to jump **from View1 to View3** but when I use back button from View3, it pops to View2 . 
If I use following code

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

it does not work cause of indexing, at this time View3 has index value 2 when I push the View3 from View 1.

So is there any other method to pop View2 from View3 using back button?

Comment: It's not clear what you want  jump from View1 to View3 needs pushing or pop View2 from View3 needs poping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new class `MYViewController : UIViewController` with `initWithBackButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)backButton;`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *saveBackButton

- (id)initWithBackButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)backButton {

  self = [super init];

  if(self){
      self.saveBackButton = backButton;
  }
  return self;
}
```

in root

Create 3 property vc1, vc2,vc3;

when you create `MYViewController`

```
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(iWantToOpenNumber2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    self.vc3 = [[MYViewController alloc] initWithBackButton:backItem];
}

- (void)iWantToOpenNumber2:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: ^{
       [self presentViewController:self.vc2 animated: YES completion:^{}]; 
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the view1 in view3 then create an instance for view1 and paste this code

```
UIViewController *view1Reference = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:view1Reference animated:YES];
```

Comment: is you using story board?

Comment: then use customized back button, call an action from that button and in that action use this code..

Comment: Ok then add UIButton to Navigation bar and call an action , in that action use this code..

UIViewController *view1Reference = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:view1Reference animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

via back button. (for specific index)

```
NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:2] animated:NO];
```

(for previous view)

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```